# Google Cloud Platform access tensorboard

Tags: unix, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard

I am new to Google Cloud (and unix) and have been using `ml-engine` to train a neural net using Tensorflow.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/monitor-training) it says that you can monitor the app using `tensorboard`. How can I access the `tensorboard` panel? When I run it (from the Cloud Shell Access console) it says it's running at http://0.0.0.0:6006

I don't know the IP of the Cloud Shell console, how can I access the tensorboard panel?

The command I run (and output):

```
tensorboard --logdir=gs://model_output
Starting TensorBoard 47 at http://0.0.0.0:6006
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest is to adjust your command to:
`tensorboard --logdir=gs://model_output --port=8080`

E.g. adding `--port=8080` to your command, which allows you to just use the default [Web Preview option of Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I want to give some other suggestions. The solution from @Fematich is very helpful. The small glitch here is that `8080` is the default port, and usually we may run `jupyterlab` on this port. So, my suggestion is that you need to ssh to two sessions; one on `port 8080` and one on `port 6006`. Then run `tensorboard` in the session on `port 8080`, and open web-preview in the second session with changing the port from default 8080 to 6006. So you can update your model in one session freely and observe the graph in another session. I found it pretty helpful.